# Yammer Customization

Tags: javascript, yammer

I am curretly working on yammer feed customization. Does the /platform/yam.js reference is needed? I want to confirm because this reference needs an update for the current yammer i am using. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The urls for client-side yammer integration have changed. Please see the updated docs. http://developer.yammer.com/documentation/

For Embed UI integration - https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js

For Javascript SDK only - https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js